# Given some integer N, how many bases b are there such that the base-b representation of N starts with a 1?

Tags: c, math

This question is asked in one of codechef competitions.I have tried it in c. Below is my code:

```
    scanf("%d",&N);
    count=0;
    for(i=2;i<=N;i++)
    {

        c=a;
        while(c>=i)
           {
               c=c/i;
           }
           if(b==1)
             count++;
    }

    printf("%d\n",count);
```

But this is giving me only partial marks. Can it be solved in lesser time? If so, how?

Comment: What is `a`? Should that be `N`?

Comment: Instead of dividing in a loop, calculate the log of N base i, then divide by `i**floor(log)`.

Comment: Where do you set `b`? Should that be `c`?

Comment: Whether that will be faster depends on how big `N` is. For small numbers, the loop will probably be faster than calculating the log and exponent.

Comment: If I we want to answer codechef question, what woul dkeep us from doing them ourselves? It would not be fair to the others if we did  and you post it as your's, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest number with a leading 1 and `d` digits in base `b` is `10...0` which is `b^(d-1)`.

The largest such number is `2*b^(d-1)-1`. Thus the bases such that a given number `N` falls inside that range are given by the inequalities

```
pow(0.5*(N+1), 1.0/(d-1) ) <= b <= pow(N, 1.0/(d-1) )
```

With appropriate rounding, taking into account random floating point errors, you can directly count how many integer `b` are inside these boundaries.